# Iterate child entity item and get in one object as appropriate entity from the parent entity object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> > I have three or more class like class A,B,C and among them Class A is
> >     parent and its referential to the class B,C and so on.
> >
> > So by the navigation property i can get Child class list inside object
> >     of Class A in entity framework but  here i want  get the separate
> >     child class object from the object of A.
>
> I want to do this thing dynamic  way because there is an more than 50 Class referential to A.

Classes structure like following way as per code-first approach

```
public partial class A
        {
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
            public A()
            {
                B = new HashSet<B>();
                C = new HashSet<C>();
                D = new HashSet<D>();
            }
            [Key]
            public int AId { get; set; }
            [StringLength(300)]
            public string xyz { get; set; }
            [StringLength(300)]
            public string abc { get; set; }
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<B> B { get; set; }
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<C> C { get; set; }
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<D> D { get; set; }
        }
    }
    public partial class B
    {
        [Key]
        public int BId { get; set; }
        public int? AId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(300)]
        public string byz { get; set; }
        public virtual StyleA StyleA { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class C
    {
        [Key]
        public int CId { get; set; }
        public int? AId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(300)]
        public string cyz { get; set; }
        public virtual StyleA StyleA { get; set; }
    }
```

at quick watch point of view i am able to see list of B,C which has relation to A in list object of A so from this i want to get separate B,C object from object A

Comment: please share some relevant code.